# Neo4j - query profiler - understanding some things

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Lets consider some result of `profile` of query in Cypher:

[image]

I know that AllNodesScan means full scan on nodestore file.
1. Can anyone explain me what does it mean `db hits`?
2. What does it mean Expand(All) ?  Why we have here more db hits than in previous step ?
3. What does it mean `anon` ?
4. What is role of estimated rows?

Answer (score 0):

1. ***Database Hit*** is a unit of work the database engine has to do. Different actions cause different numbers of database hits such a retrieving or updating data.

   For more information see [Neo4J Developer Manuel - Execution Plan - DB Hits](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/execution-plans/#execution-plans-dbhits)
2. ***ExpandAll*** traverses incoming and outgoing relationships.

   For more information see [Neo4J Developer Manuel - Execution Plan - ExpandAll](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/execution-plans/operators/#query-plan-expand-all)
3. I am not sure about this point but as far as I know **Anon** stands for anonymous identifier/variable/node. In your example u, w are non-anonymous nodes because you defined them while all other nodes are anon/unnamed.
4. ***Estimated Rows*** is an approximation of the result rows that will be produced by the (current) operator. The database compiler uses this number to choose a suitable execution plan.

   For more information see [Neo4J Developer Manuel - Execution Plan - Estimed Rows](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/execution-plans/#execution-plans)